# Linear equation and triangles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a linear equation pass through the point(6,4) and two axes, and formed a triangle with area 6. I want to find the equation of that line.

My attempt is letting the equation be $\frac{y-4}{x-6}=m$
Then using the fact that the area of triangle is 6, forming the equation $\frac{1}{2}\text{base}*\text{height}=6$. I got the base and height of the triangle from the axes, $\text{base} = 6-\frac{4}{m}$ and $\text{height}=4-6m$

Then substitute the equation $\frac{1}{2}\text{base}*\text{height}=6$ and get $36m^2-36m+16=0$ which leads to no solution.
Can anyone let me know what's wrong?

Comment: What do you call the base of the triangle here?

Comment: The problem is, that the triangle contains a rectangle with sides 4 and 6, which has the area 24 (if I understand well)

Comment: @Bernard base=6-4/m

Comment: @user376343 How can a triangle with area 6 contains a rectangle with area 24?

Comment: I'm not asking for the value, but what it is? Thinking a bit more about, what call the base is  the $x$-intercept, and the height is the $y$-intercept (or their absolute values).

Comment: @BrianWu it can be a linguistic issue in my case. I've imagined the point $(6,4),$ a line through this point cutting the axes, and the triangle with vertices: the intersection points with the axes and $(0,0).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get if calculated correctly
$36m^2-60m+16=0$

Comment: How do you get -60m instead of -36m?

Comment: I got a $\text{base} = \frac{4}{m}-6$

Comment: There can be 4 different combinations because of the absolute value of base and height. Does that mean that I need to solve them one by one to get the correct form of base?

Comment: Correct, but only 2 cases need to be considered as sign combination ++/-- and -+/+- is the same. You get the two quadratic equations
$36m^2+36m-16=0$ and $36m^2-60m+16=0$
with solutions
f(x)=$\frac{1}{3}$x+2 and f(x)=$\frac{-4}{3}$x+12 and f(x)=$\frac{4}{3}$x-4

Answer (score 0):

The equation is given by $$y=mx+n$$ so $$y=m(x-6)+n$$ since $$P(6;4)$$ is situated on the line. An both intersection Points are $$A(0;4-6m)$$ and $$P(\frac{6m-4}{m},0)$$. The area our triangle is giveb by$$A=\frac{1}{2}\left|4-6m\right|\left|\frac{6m-4}{m}\right|$$